# Can I play the PAL version of Battlefield 3 on a NTSC xbox360?

Tags: xbox-360, battlefield-3

Can I play Battlefield 3 PAL on NTSC-U XBox 360?

Is it region free or locked? Does anyone have a hands-on experience doing this? I tried finding information, but didn't find any  so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [one source](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120125120059AABrt09) that says that it works fine, and a few posts on this [EA Forum](http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/7658069.page) also say that it works fine.
Unfortunately I cannot confirm this myself as I have a PAL console.

Comment: yes it works fine...

Comment: Good to hear. Thanks for posting the outcome, Sandeep.

Answer (score -1):

I found a [chart](http://gaming.wikia.com/wiki/Region_Free_Xbox_360_Games) that says the PAL version should work fine with an NTSC/U Xbox 360, unless you bought a PAL version intended for sale in Germany, Poland, or Russia:

Note that games sold in and intended for use in Germany, Poland and Russia are very likely to be region-locked even though other PAL-country versions of the same game are not.

Note also that the same source says that it won't work with an NTSC/J Xbox 360.